# What do the different colors signify in the diep.io class chart?

Tags: diep.io

If you look at [the class chart shown on the diep.io wiki](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Tiers), you'll see there seems to be a color coding scheme using yellow, blue, red, and green, but there's no key. Can anyone explain what the different colors indicate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not definitive, but as mentioned on the wiki

> Interestingly, there is a recurring pattern of colors in the upgrade selection menu and the Class Tree. The first tank will always have a light blue background. The second will be green. The third will be red. The fourth will be yellow. The fifth will be dark blue, and the sixth will be purple (This order can be found in tank's add stats buttons which are color-reversed). Regardless of speculation, **colors do not seem to represent anything other than a simple order pattern to more easily discern tanks apart when quickly selecting an upgrade**

Note that Tank->Twin is light blue, and adds an forward extra barrel, while Machine Gun->Gunner has a similar effect, but in a different color.

It is interesting that tanks which appear in multiple paths (Twin Flank and Quad Tank) have the same color both times, but they have been placed in the same order to keep the pattern.

Image below for observing the tank pattern.

[image]

Comment: Maybe the colors signify the time a tank was added to the game. What do you think about that? Maybe red=added late, blue=first tanks , etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a key but never added

It's now shown as [1], [2]

If you click 1 or any other numbers then you upgrade for it.
You can use E to auto shoot too and C to autospin

If you want to know how to calculate those upgrade abilities then look up on their reddit.

Answer (score 0):

nothing, they are just for decoration.

Comment: This directly conflicts with other answers. Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's just to recommend a tank class in a list.

1. Purple - Unique, Extremely Good (With High Skill)...Factory has drones with bullets. It's unique and has gotten to first place multiple times.
2. Dark Blue - Rare, Very Good (With High Skill)...Battleship, Auto-Trapper, and Smasher have easily gotten on the scoreboard many times. They are a little hard to control though and require skill.
3. Red - High In Value, Great (With Skill)...Examples such as the Machine Gun, Manager, Spike, and Over Trapper have high defense and attack

These are the best class colors

Answer (score -1):

It's a class specialization and bonus.

- Yellow is Bullet Penetration
- Red is Bullet Damage
- Green is Reload
- Blue is Movement Speed

When you upgrade to specific class you get some bonus to this characteristics along with some negative effects.
More info about bonuses / penalities of different classes [here](http://diepio.wikia.com/wiki/Upgrades).
Info about colors in-game:
[image: Upgrades]

Comment: I actually don't see any relevant info in that source. Where on that wiki page does it mention colors?

Comment: @Aerovistae this page says which characteristics are reduced and which increases depending on the class. Comparing them with [this](http://zoneasoluces.fr/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/guide-complet-pour-Diep.io-c.png) picture and performing simple mental effort, it is possible to understand the meaning of the classes colors. I will add this picture to the answer.

Comment: Your linked source specifically says Sniper has a decreased rate of fire, while Machine Gun has increased rate of fire and decreased damage. Your suggested color coding scheme implies the contrary.

Comment: @Aerovistae is right, some of the colors are clearly not representing the characteristics of the tank, like the spike whose red indicates "high bullet damage"; alas, it doesn't have any bullets. Whether these are simple mistakes or whether the theory is wrong I'm not sure.